# How do I get the HTML of a wiki page with Pywikibot?

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, pywikibot

I'm using pywikibot-core, and I used before another python Mediawiki API wrapper as [Wikipedia.py](https://github.com/goldsmith/Wikipedia) (which has a .HTML method). I switched to pywikibot-core 'cause I think it has many more features, but I can't find a similar method. 
(beware: I'm not very skilled).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll post here user283120 second answer, more precise than the first one:

Pywikibot core doesn't support any direct (HTML) way to interact to Wiki, so you should use API. 
If you need to, you can do it easily by using urllib2.

This is an example I used to get HTML of a wiki page in commons:

    `import urllib2
...
    url = "https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/" + page.title().replace(" ","_")
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I set my answer as community wiki, you could just have edited it. :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a total newbie here, and also with reputation 1 I don't think I could've edited anything. If you want to paste this answer in yours, I'm totally fine :-).

Answer (score 1):

"[saveHTML.py] downloads the HTML-pages of articles and images and saves the interesting parts, i.e. the article-text and the footer to a file"

source: https://git.wikimedia.org/blob/pywikibot%2Fcompat.git/HEAD/saveHTML.py

Comment: Thanks valepert. But this is a script right? ANd it is just in pywikibot-compat or also in core? I'm always confused :-S

Answer (score 1):

IIRC you want the HTML of the entire pages, so you need something that uses [api.php?action=parse](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext#parse). In Python I'd often just use [wikitools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikitools) for such a thing, I don't know about PWB or the other requirements you have.

Comment: Thanks user283120, I also came to that conclusion. I would like (if it exists!) a direct PWB method: I decided to use it under the impression that it's the most complete software to cope with Mediawiki-based websites...

Comment: PWB is focused on editing and similar operations. I often end up using lower level API modules than PWB easily affords, but that might be just me.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should use pywikibot instead of wikipedia (e.g. instead of "import wikipedia" you should use "import pywikibot") and if you are looking for methods and class that were been in wikipedia.py, they are now separated and can be found in pywikibot folder (mainly in page.py and site.py)

If you want to run your scripts that you wrote in compat, you can use a script in pywikibot-core named compat2core.py (in scripts folder) and there is a detailed help about conversion named README-conversion.txt, read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The Mediawiki API has a parse action which allows to get the html snippet for the wikimarkup as returned by the Mediawiki markup parser.

For the [pywikibot library](https://pypi.org/project/pywikibot/) there is already a function implemented which you can use like this:

```py
def getHtml(self,pageTitle):
        '''
        get the HTML code for the given page Title
        
        Args:
            pageTitle(str): the title of the page to retrieve
            
        Returns:
            str: the rendered HTML code for the page
        '''
        page=self.getPage(pageTitle)
        html=page._get_parsed_page()
        return html
```

When using the [mwclient python library](https://pypi.org/project/mwclient/) there is a generic api method see:
https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient/blob/master/mwclient/client.py

Which can be used to retrieve the html code like this:

```py
def getHtml(self,pageTitle):
        '''
        get the HTML code for the given page Title
        
        Args:
            pageTitle(str): the title of the page to retrieve
        '''
        api=self.getSite().api("parse",page=pageTitle)
        if not "parse" in api:
            raise Exception("could not retrieve html for page %s" % pageTitle)
        html=api["parse"]["text"]["*"]
        return html
```

As shown above this gives a [duck typed interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which is implemented in the [py-3rdparty-mediawiki](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-3rdparty-mediawiki) library for which i am a committer. This was resolved with closing [issue 38 - add html page retrieval](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-3rdparty-mediawiki/issues/38)

Comment: Can you give a working example of `getHtml` with `pywikibot`? `grep` does not find any instance of `getHtml` in the codebase.

Comment: it's getPage in pywikibot and .api("parse") in mwclient. The code above is not in the library but shows how to use it.

Answer (score -1):

With Pywikibot you may use `http.request()` to get the html content:

```
import pywikibot
from pywikibot.comms import http
site = pywikibot.Site('wikipedia:en')
page = pywikibot.Page(s, 'Elvis Presley')
path = '{}/index.php?title={}'.format(site.scriptpath(), page.title(as_url=True))
r = http.request(site, path)
print(r[94:135])
```

This should give the html content

```
'<title>Elvis Presley – Wikipedia</title>\n'
```

With Pywikibot **6.0** `http.request()` gives a `requests.Response` object rather than plain text. In this case you must use the text Attribute:

```
print(r.text[94:135])
```

to get the same result.